# How to display the symbolic form of an equation?

Tags: manipulate

I have this problem. I want to show the unassessed form of the equations that I enter in the graph, however, every equation that I introduce results in the substitution of the known values within the equation.

```
a*x^2 + 2*y + 1 -> 5*x^2 + 2*y + 1
```

where a = 5

```
Manipulate[a = 5;
           Grid[
                {
                 {TraditionalForm[u]},
                 {"Equation", Row[{u, " = 0"}]},
                 {Plot3D[u, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}
                }, Alignment -> Left],
           {{u, a*x^2 + 2*y + 1, "Equation"}}, 
           BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Optima"]]
```

I have tried with `{"Equation", Row[{HoldForm[u], " = 0"}]},` but it did not work.

Comment: But it will only work for that case and not for any other equation that you write when you run the Manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
Clear[a]
Manipulate[
 aa = 5;
 Grid[{{TraditionalForm[u]}, {"Equation", Row[{u, " = 0"}]}, 
       {Plot3D[u /. a -> aa, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}}, 
        Alignment -> Left], 
 {{u, a*x^2 + 2*y + 1, "Equation"}}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Optima"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Works correctly.
A suitable solution.